# stop a described jQuery function on hover and start it back on mouseleave

Tags: jquery, html, hover, mouseleave

I have a jQuery function `func1` that works fine on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
   //func1 description is here
   ...
   $(func1);
}
```

also I have

```
$(function ()
{
            $("#my-ul a").hover(function ()
            {
               //do something on my-ul a hover
            });
            $("#my-ul a").mouseleave(function ()
            {
               //do something on my-ul a mouseleave
            });
});
```

and it works fine.

What I want as well is to stop `func1` on `my-ul a hover` and start it again on `my-ul a mouseleave` (like you didn't hover at all).

Browsing stackoverflow didn't help me with the answer. I believe .stop() function should be used, but I had no luck to use it properly for my example.

Thank you.

Update:
Here is an [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv2KV/7/) and I want to stop changing text when hovered on link and start changing the same way onmouseleave back.

Comment: Please post was $(func1) does - maybe stop() can be used after all...

Comment: it is a recursive function, continues indefinite number of times for changing a text in a div using .fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut(200, func1);

Comment: OK thanks for the info - simple stop() seems out of question ;-)

Comment: I've just put the link to jsFiddle in my question: http://jsfiddle.net/Dv2KV/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not cancel `delay`, you need to use `setTimeout` or `serInterval` instead.

The code (***[THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv2KV/9/)***):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var terms = ["span_aaa", "span_bbb", "span_ccc", "span_ddd", "span_eee", "span_fff"],
        i = 0,
        intervalId = null;

    function rotateTerm() {
        $("#text-content").fadeOut(200, function () {
            $(this).text($('#text-slider .' + terms[i]).html() + i).fadeIn(200);
        });
        $("#title-content").fadeOut(200, function () {
            $(this).text($('#title-slider .' + terms[i]).html() + i).fadeIn(200);
            i == terms.length - 1 ? i = 0 : i++;
        });
    }
    rotateTerm();
    intervalId = setInterval(rotateTerm, 2000);
    $('#stop-on-hover').hover(function () {
        if (intervalId) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }, function () {
        intervalId = setInterval(rotateTerm, 2000);
    });
});​
```

Comment: So how can I stop my function when hovered? Thank you.

Comment: @xdazz He's asking to stop and start a function not an animation. See the fiddle example.

Comment: xdazz, I'm sorry, but how to animate the function?  http://api.jquery.com/animate/   .animate( properties, options )
Could you please provide a working example? Thanks. Sorry for asking again.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose two options:

1. Use Javascript `setTimeout` instead of `delay` since you can stop the former. Here's an example of how it would play out. See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mhusaini/XQRgm/1/).

   ```
   var thread = null;

   function rotateTerm() {
       var ct = $("#text-content").data("term") || 0;

       function fadeIn() {
           $("#text-content").data("term", ct == terms.length - 1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text($('#text-slider .' + terms[ct]).html() + ct).fadeIn();
           $("#title-content").text($('#title-slider .' + terms[ct]).html() + ct).fadeIn();
       }

       function fadeOut(callback) {
           $("#text-content").fadeOut(200);
           $("#title-content").fadeOut(200, callback);
       }

       fadeIn();
       thread = window.setTimeout(function() {
           fadeOut(rotateTerm);
       }, 2000);
   }

   rotateTerm();
   $("a#stop-on-hover").hover(function() {
       thread && window.clearTimeout(thread);
   }, function() {
       rotateTerm();
   });
   ```
2. Set a flag that tells your code whether to continue the animation or stop it and you can change it on hover in and hover out. Here's an example. See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mhusaini/gggu6/1/). There is some flicker, but you can play around with the code to make it work right.

   ```
   var animate = true;

   function rotateTerm() {
       var ct = $("#text-content").data("term") || 0;

       function fadeIn() {
           $("#text-content").data("term", ct == terms.length - 1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text($('#text-slider .' + terms[ct]).html() + ct).fadeIn();
           $("#title-content").text($('#title-slider .' + terms[ct]).html() + ct).fadeIn();
       }

       function fadeOut(callback) {
           $("#text-content").fadeOut(200);
           $("#title-content").fadeOut(200, callback);
       }

       fadeIn();

       window.setTimeout(function() {
           if (animate) {
               fadeOut(rotateTerm);
           }
       }, 2000);
   }

   rotateTerm();
   $("a#stop-on-hover").hover(function() {
       animate = false;
   }, function() {
       animate = true;
       rotateTerm();
   });
   ```